# Change anchor text on click with...? jQuery maybe?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is an anchor / toggle which opens and closes a drawer like navigation. I want the icon / text to change once it's clicked. But my jQuery is so basic i'm struggling with this atm.

```
<a data-target=".navbar-responsive-collapse" data-toggle="collapse" class="btn btn-navbar ss-icon drawer">&#xEB01;</a>
```

Help is appreciated.
/Paul

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This should do .

```
$('.btn.btn-navbar').on('click', function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     $(this).text(function(i,v) {
           return v === 'Show' ? 'Hide' : 'Show';
     });
});
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/Me5kn/)**

Try this approach

```
var flag = true;
$('.btn.btn-navbar').on('click', function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     $(this).html(function(i,v) {
           return flag === true  ? '&#1514;' : '&#xEB01;';
     });
     flag = !flag;
});
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/Me5kn/1/)**

Comment: oh thanks man! works great. Do you have an idea how to get an entity like &#xEB01; work? Is shows the entity code instead of the wanted icon.